# Initializing state information to be used in a React.js SPA

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This may be a newbie question...

I've written an SPA myself quite some time ago, without any framework really.  There was a logon process, and once logged on, I would generate the app page, including all the HTML, css, and js needed. When generating the HTML for that single page, I had the ability to do server side lookups and queries and so forth to "customize" the static HTML to be rendered.  In effect, I was able to pass it initial state information, such as version numbers, the user's name and other attributes, and other things that were retrieved server side but rendered either statically or in some cases "hard coded" in static js variable initializations.

Now we are creating a React.js app. This SPA gets loaded once logged on via Razor pages as well.  I'd like to pass in some initial state information along with the rendered HTML, but I don't know what kind of markup one would use to do so, or if this is even possible.  If the React components are "compiled" into static objects, and there is no server-side process responsible for customizing them when requested, I guess all state information must be retrieved through an AJAX API call made very early in the process.

My question therefore is this - is there a way to "customize" the components when they are retrieved from the server? Or is the model best followed by rendering the SPA statically, and let it retrieve the initial state via an early API call if needed.  If it is possible to customize the rendered output, where should I be looking for more information on how to do it properly?

Comment: If you're using plain express to serve your app, you can perform necessary server-side logic there, while building up HTML response. If you use next.js, you may leverage [embedded feature](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps) to initialize necessary props.

Comment: In future versions of React, it may be addressed naturally with [server components](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/12/21/data-fetching-with-react-server-components.html)